# average plot of multiple plots in python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, average

I have a data in a numpy array with multiple arrays inside of them, and I need to extract the average of each position array to plot a average plot of this data. What is the best way to do this?

**Example of how the data is storage:**

```
array([[ 0.00474308,  0.00513834,  0.00513834, ...,  0.00395257,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206],
       [ 0.00474308,  0.00474308,  0.00513834, ...,  0.00395257,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206],
       [ 0.00474308,  0.00434783,  0.00513834, ...,  0.00395257,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206],
       ..., 
       [ 0.00513834,  0.00513834,  0.0055336 , ...,  0.00316206,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206],
       [ 0.00474308,  0.00474308,  0.0055336 , ...,  0.00316206,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206],
       [ 0.00474308,  0.00474308,  0.00513834, ...,  0.00355731,
         0.00355731,  0.00316206]])
```

The new array need to contain the following format:

```
array([ avg(arr1[0]+arr2[0]+...+arrN[0]), avg(arr1[1]+arr2[1]+...+arrN[1]),...,avg(arr1[N]+arr2[N]+...+arrN[N])])
```

The picture bellow illustrate all data plotted in a graph.

[image: This picture illustrate all data plotted in a graph]

Comment: I answered your question but you didn't leave enough of a code example for me to be sure that the answer will work for you. In general it's best to ask questions that include a runnable code snippet, that way it's unambiguous that asker and answerer are talking about the same code.

Comment: @nathan12343, please check the edited post, where I put some piece of data and a best explanation of my case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the data are stored in a 2D array with the time axis along the first dimension and the graph index in the second dimension, something like:

```
arr.mean(axis=-1)
```